# Node js + Mongodb better way to select count of specific documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, optimization, mongodb-query

What would be the better way to select count of users

Will the JavaScript filtering code work fine if the number of users increases?

1. Using multiple mongodb requests

   ```
    const db = fastify.mongo.db;
    const users_collection = await db.collection('users');

    let users = {
        registered: {
            count: null,
            typed_count: {
                vk: null,
                ok: null,
                google: null,
                oneclick: null,
            },
        },
    };

    users.registered.count = await users_collection.countDocuments();
    users.registered.typed_count.vk = await users_collection.countDocuments({ 'social.vk': { $exists: true } });
    users.registered.typed_count.ok = await users_collection.countDocuments({ 'social.ok': { $exists: true } });
    users.registered.typed_count.google = await users_collection.countDocuments({ 'social.google': { $exists: true } });
    users.registered.typed_count.oneclick = await users_collection.countDocuments({ social: { $exists: false } });
   ```
2. Using one mongodb request and javascript filtering

   ```
    const db = fastify.mongo.db;
    const users_collection = await db.collection('users');

    let users = {
        registered: {
            count: null,
            typed_count: {
                vk: null,
                ok: null,
                google: null,
                oneclick: null,
            },
        },
    };

    const data = await (await users_collection.find()).toArray();
    users.registered.count = data.length;
    users.registered.typed_count.vk = data.filter((obj) => obj.social && obj.social.vk).length;
    users.registered.typed_count.ok = data.filter((obj) => obj.social && obj.social.ok).length;
    users.registered.typed_count.google = data.filter((obj) => obj.social && obj.social.google).length;
    users.registered.typed_count.oneclick = data.filter((obj) => !obj.social).length;
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The First Method** will take more time as too many `network requests` are involved
and

---

**The Second Method** will take too much of your `server's memory (RAM)` as all the documents will first be brought into the memory.

So we can reduce both time and memory by using MongoDB `aggregation's` `$group` pipeline, which will look something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      vk: {
        $sum: {
            $cond: [{ $gt: ["$social.vk", null]}, 1, 0]
        }
      },
      ok: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ $gt: ["$social.ok", null]}, 1, 0]
        }
      },
      google: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ $gt: ["$social.google", null]}, 1, 0]
        }
      },
      oneclick: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ $lte: ["$social", null]}, 1, 0]
        }
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

[Working Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6mWB_rYkoCr)